# How to get my token and user from the backend to the front-end

Tags: angular, typescript, access-token, subscribe

[image: Error Image]

This is my userservice.ts file code

```js
export class UserService {

  BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8082";
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {}

  public login(loginData:any){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.BASE_URL+"/authenticate",loginData);
  
  } 
}
```

this is my login.component.ts file

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService:UserService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  login(loginFormData:NgForm){
    this.userService.login(loginFormData.value).subscribe(
      (response) =>{
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the server response you can acces your token and using interceptors you can append the token to any future requests if verification is needed.

Comment: but the error is still there. token and user details not coming to the front-end(console-log)